# Javascript sort function with two conditions to be met

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am want to sort messages where both important equals 1 and read equals 0 to be put at the beginning of the array.

I have an array of these message objects:

```
{
archived: 0
draftMode: 0
entry_date: "Mar 22, 2022"
important: 1
message: "Hello world"
messageId: 1
pinned: 0
read: 0
subject: "test"
}
```

The code I am using to sort is:

```
messages.sort((a, b) => (a.important > b.important && a.read < b.read ? -1 : 1))
```

Comment: what other values do you have for `important` and `read`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming only `0` and `1` (why not use booleans?), you could take the delta of the values (works for booleans as well).

```js
const
    messages = [
        { important: 0, read: 0 },
        { important: 0, read: 1 },
        { important: 1, read: 0 },
        { important: 1, read: 1 },
    ];

messages.sort((a, b) => 
    a.read - b.read ||
    b.important - a.important
);

console.log(messages);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I'd personally prioritize unread before important (U & I, U & U, I & R, U & R) so if you just switch the operations for the pipes it works that way. It would look like `a.read - b.read || b.important - a.important`

Comment: @MattCroak, yes. i changed it. maybe op can add what is more relevant.